# Export jTable selection to excel and open excel

Tags: java, swing, excel, export, jtable

I have a jtable with lots of records;I need to select some of the records in the jTable and output it to excel along with the jTable Header of selected columns.The excel should open automatically with the selected data on exporting.

thank you

Comment: You should post what have you tried so far...

Comment: this question is about cca. 5-20 separated questions

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code for creating a file from JTable

```
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file,true));
    PrintWriter fileWriter = new PrintWriter(bufferedWriter);

    for(int i=0; i<model.getRowCount(); ++i)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<model.getColumnCount(); ++j)
        {
            String s = model.getValueAt(i,j).toString();
            fileWriter.print(s + ",");

        }
        fileWriter.println("\n");
    }   
    fileWriter.close();
```

What this code is doing is creating a CSV file and you need to work for how to create files and what is csv file and how can you open it.

Comment: I got a good answer from : http://rickproctor.wordpress.com/2006/08/29/exporting-jtable-data-to-excel/     Thanks Rahul

Comment: You can use that, you should have found this good answer before posting a question here.